# Can someone please tell me how to code a Continue button to return a games activty from where it was stopped?

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

I need to Code a button in the Main menu which can resume the game from the state where it was stopped.

Comment: Im Really sorry for not being Specific, Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity `onPause` method, save the state of your game to a file (or a SQLite).

In your activity `onResume`, check if there is saved state, and if there is one, add one more entry to your main menu. Upon pressing that menu item, read the game state from the file and restore it in memory.

You can read on the various storage options in the [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) page.

Comment: I dont understand how its done can someone show me a demo version.

Answer (score 0):

Save the state every 10 seconds while playing.